# How to read differences in state onChange instead of entire state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text-editor, rich-text-editor, lexicaljs

I know I can get the current state of the editor whenever a change is made by doing the following:

Set up the onChange plugin:

```
<OnChangePlugin onChange={onChange} />
```

And then I can access the updated state in onChange:

```
const onChange = (editorState: EditorState, editor: LexicalEditor) => {
    // do something with the new state here
}
```

However, when the state is very large, processing it can be costly. Is there no way to get the **diff** in state or the **action** that was performed when an edit occurs?

Example, let's say I want to detect if a certain character has been entered. Currently, I would have to read the entire state and scan for that character. However, if I had something like "Insert X character at postion whatever" then I could tell without scanning the entire state.

Comment: Objects make things more complicated in state. If you set the state to any value and it's a new reference, React will re-render *even if the Object contents are the same*. kca's answer is great advice

Comment: Any diff they provided would presumably need to be created by doing the expensive processing you seek to avoid. I don't think this is possible to avoid.